# Django (hard question): How to allow users to write text and insert specific tags/variables that my app will then fill with values on the BE

Tags: django, django-templates

This is an hard one (I think).

I have a django app and I am trying to build a specific editor tool to help users write email templates.

Basically, a user should be able to write simple text for an email but also insert tags/variables in specific spots that will then be filled with values. Almost like if they were create a django template.

So imagine that a user would write something like:

```
" Hi, <employee name>

I am very happy to inform you that you have been confirmed for the position of <position name> for the upcoming <project_type> <project_name>...."
```

And on the backend I would transform that into:

```
" Hi, Mike

I am very happy to inform you that you have been confirmed for the position of Product Designer for the upcoming feature film Titanic...."
```

Currently I have a solution where the main structure of the email is the one I built and users can't really change it. (So it's just one template) but I would like to allow users to create their own templates. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this using dev exrepress variables html editor

https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Components/dxHtmlEditor/Configuration/variables/